# Can't connect to android studio emulator with expo project on WSL2/Linux Subsystem , Error: spawn <correct adb location> ENOENT

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo, wsl-2

I'm currently trying to develop a react native application using expo, I created and initialized the project using the Expo CLI, and have no problems using the Expo Go app on my own mobile device and connected via a tunneled connection (`npx expo start --tunnel`).

The issue I'm having now is connecting my sdk correctly to run the expo android script by pressing `a` in the terminal. The specific error I'm getting in my case is:
`Error: spawn /mnt/c/Users/Mo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb ENOENT`

I have followed various stack overflow articles and medium articles to get the point where I've correctly set my ANDROID_HOME variable in my `.bashrc` on my linux distribution. One of the articles mentioned a specific issue that occurs when running tools from linux is that the .exe extension must be added otherwise it will not work, problem is this is handled by expo and I have no idea how to solve this issue.

For context this is what is in my `.bashrc`

```
# Android
export ANDROID_HOME="/mnt/c/Users/Mo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk"
export WSLENV=ANDROID_HOME/p
```

If anyone has found a solution to this problem or knows of a workaround, please let me know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of removing this post I'm going to update with the fix that I found! I ended up coming up with a solution and solving all my problems, albeit may not be the most elegant solution.

This is a common issue on Linux not being able to find the file with the extension, luckily in this case I was able to simply create a copy of adb.exe called just adb which allowed the script to be run properly from my Linux distribution. I also wrote a full guide, documenting the steps if anyone else gets stuck on this same issue!

[Full In-Depth Guide](https://medium.com/@akbarimo/developing-react-native-with-expo-android-emulators-on-wsl2-linux-subsystem-ad5a8b0fa23c)